# QDISC_BYPASS in Python (Raw Sockets)

Tags: python, sockets, setsockopt

How do I set the socket options on a raw socket to have QDISC_BYPASS enabled? I saw examples in C but wasn't able to understand clearly how to implement it in Python.
I constructed the socket with AF_PACKET and SOCK_RAW settings.

I understand that I need to use socket.setsockopt() method but I'm not sure how to call it correctly in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured this out myself. **You need linux kernel 3.14 or higher installed for it to work**

```
sock.setsockopt(263, 20, 0);
```

263 (int) is a reference to SOL_PACKET

20 (int) is a reference to QDISC_BYPASS

I wrote out the numbers in case they are not defined in your socket module (i.e. socket.SOL_PACKET doesn't exist)